# Can we show the product of two connected topological space is connected by a proof by contradiction?

Tags: general-topology

Most proofs that shows the product of two connected spaces are connected uses the theorem that a space is connected iff every continuous function to {0,1} is constant or it uses the horizontal or vertical slice trick and take the union of all slices.

I was wondering if there is a "direct" proof by contradiction possible. If $X \times Y$ is the product of two connected space, and we assume $X \times Y$, then there is a disconnection possible: we can write it as a union of two disjoint non-empty open sets. Can we then make use of this to prove that either $X$ or $Y$ has a disconnection? Basically we can express $U$ and $V$ as unions as basic open sets in the product topology.

Comment: @FSrike that is not true, there are plenty of easy counterexamples of disconected sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose projections are connected.

Comment: @FShrike for some reason, i thought we needed to express U and V as basic open sets first... but I just remembered the projection is itself a open map.

Comment: @Marcos Apologies. I am right in thinking however that they cannot possibly have connected projections in all coordinates?

Comment: @FShrike No, take two concentric (disjoint) circles in $\Bbb R^2$, their projection is always a segment

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Wow my intuition is really off today.. apologies again and thank you for the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct proof by contradiction as you want. Why? Because if we say $X\times Y$ is not connected, then there exists open sets $U,V$ such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$ and $X\times Y=U\cup V$. If we can say that $U=U_X\times U_Y$ and $V=V_X\times V_Y$ then we will be done. But sadlly, this is not true, since every subset of a cartesian product need not be equal to a cartesian product. Of course it is if we consider basis elements, but we don't have any reason tho think that $U$ and $V$ belong to the basis.

The only easy approach by contradiction I can find is to use the standard proof of ''taking the union of all the slices'' and arguing by contradiction here. But I know that is not what you are looking for, since it is exactlly the same proof with just a slightly variation.

Comment: I thought it might have been possible to write $U=\bigcup (A_i \times B_i)$ and  $V=\bigcup (A_j \times B_j)$ and then we have $\bigcup (A_i \times B_i) \bigcap  \bigcup(A_j \times B_j)=\emptyset$ Is there any set manipulation we can do to show that $X=(\bigcup A_i) \bigcup (\bigcup A_j) $ With this, we can express X as the union of two disconnected open set.

Comment: The problem here is that  $\bigcup A_i$ and $\bigcup A_j$ need not be disjoint but $\bigcup (A_i \times B_i) \bigcap  \bigcup(A_j \times B_j)=\emptyset$. Same happens with $Y$.

Comment: oh yeah that makes senses.